# Swift 3 / Alamofire: Cant load the table with the data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to load the data on the UItableview, I am able to see the records fetched in the output panel but not able to fetch them on the UItableview.

Please find the code below:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

var tableData = Array<Category>()
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
var category = [Category]()
var catTitle = ""
var id = ""



@IBOutlet weak var catTitleRec: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    catTitleRec.text = catTitle
    loadCategories(id:id)
}

func loadCategories(id : String) {


    let userDic : [String : AnyObject] = ["id":id as AnyObject]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in userDic {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    },to: "http://www.URL.com.au/database/results.php" , method: .post, headers: nil ,
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
                guard self != nil else {
                    return
                }
                debugPrint(response)

            }

            upload.responseJSON {  response in

                print(response)
            //    let responseJSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary


              //  print(responseJSON)



            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
        }


    })
    tableview.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return myarray.count
    return arrRes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell") as! CategoryCellTableViewCell
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

    cell.catName.text = dict["category.NAME"] as? String
    cell.total?.text = dict["TOTAL"] as? String


    return cell
}
```

}

and my CategoryCellTableViewCell.swift code:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var catName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

I tried to seek some help online but couldnt get  but thanks a lot  for the time :)

dict output:

```
SUCCESS: (
    {
    NAME = "COSMETIC PRODUCTS & SERVICES";
    TOTAL = 1;
    id = 54300;
},
    {
    NAME = TATTOOING;
    TOTAL = 1;
    id = 225700;
}
```

)

Comment: can you show dict output ?

Comment: Show use your `JSON` response.

Comment: @NiravD I was using the Json response, but was giving an error : thread 1: signal sigabrt

Comment: @SarahMalik Why are you using `arrRes` with `tableView` methods instead of category array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
I think you forget the filling array and also set the datasource,and delegate of UITableView

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

    var tableData = Array<Category>()
    var category = [Category]()
    var arrRes = [NSDictionary]()
    var catTitle = ""
    var id = ""



    @IBOutlet weak var catTitleRec: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        catTitleRec.text = catTitle
        loadCategories(id:id)
    }

    func loadCategories(id : String) {


        let userDic : [String : AnyObject] = ["id":id as AnyObject]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in userDic {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }

        },to: "URL" , method: .post, headers: nil ,
          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.response { [weak self] response in
                    guard self != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)

                    self.arrRes = response.result.value as? NSArray as! [NSDictionary]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error:\(encodingError)")
            }


        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return myarray.count
        return arrRes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell") as! CategoryCellTableViewCell 
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.catName.text = dict["NAME"] as? String
        cell.total?.text = dict["TOTAL"] as? String 


        return cell 
    } 



}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the problem was and how you answer solves the problem.

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, i tried to update the block, but still its not displaying any results

Comment: @SarahMalik first check is your array is filled correctly

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, well, I can see the output in the panel

Comment: what is your filled array check in debug mode is that Array<Category> you should use [category] array for tableview

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, I am so confused now.. :(

Comment: @JaydeepVyas, I dont have any clue now, I am completely lost

Comment: Shall we take this conversation to the chat and discuss?

Comment: ok simple way convert your response in format of array your array shoud be  self.arrRes = response["SUCCESS"] as! [[String: Any]]DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.tableview.reloadData()
                  } inside block and give me the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148013/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-sarah-malik).

Answer (score 0):

This asynchronous calling of method so you need do reload data inside the block as below :

```
switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
                guard self != nil else {
                    return
                }
                debugPrint(response)

            }
            upload.responseJSON {  response in
                print(response)
            //    let responseJSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
             arrRes = responseJSON // you need to assign data here
             tableview.reloadData()
              //  print(responseJSON)

            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.response { [weak self] response in
                    guard self != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
                upload.responseJSON {  response in
                    print(response)
                //    let responseJSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                  //  print(responseJSON)
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.tableview.reloadData()
                  }
                }
```

Comment: I tried using your giving suggestion, but I a not able to load the data on the tableview. Tho, i can see the output in the panel

Answer (score 0):

you are getting multiple values of name in JSON it is array of Dictionaries you need to get the name stored in dictionary its not directly in array output get it like below

```
for dict in dataDict {
      let userName = dict["NAME"] as? String
      let userTotal = dict["TOTAL"] as? String
      // Store data in User Default // Not required
      UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey:"username")
      UserDefaults.standard.set(userTotal, forKey:"totalNumber")
}
```

or add it in array and in cellforRow use the array to show the details