# how to show titles(Type) in table view using JSON Data in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

how to show titles(Type) in table view  using JSON Data in iOS Swift using the following format

[
    {
        "Id": 11000,
        "Type": "Title1"
    },
    {
        "Id": 11001,
        "Type": "Title2"
    },
    {
        "Id": 11002,
        "Type": "Title3"
    },
    {
        "Id": 11003,
        "Type": "Title4"
    }
]

Comment: post your json parsing code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838857/swift-3-alamofire-cant-load-the-table-with-the-data/44838934#44838934 try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to read titles in an array and use it as data source for tableView.

```
private func readJson( data : Data) -> [String] {
    var titlesArray = [String]()
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let jsonDict = json as? [[String: Any]] {
            for anObject in jsonDict {
                if let title = anObject["Type"] as? String {
                    titlesArray.append(title)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("JSON is invalid")
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return titlesArray
}
```

I would suggest to use SwiftyJson for json parsing. Instead of doing it manually. You can read about Swifty Json.